# UNION in AWS athena on 2 tables having billions of records

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have two tables in Athena, which has md5 as one of the columns, and both the tables have around a billion entries. I need to find md5 that is common in both tables. I was trying with the following.

```
WITH t1 as (
    SELECT table1.md5
    from table1
),
t2 as (
    SELECT table2.md5
    from table2 
)
SELECT md5 from t1 union all select md5 from t2 group by md5 having count(*)> 1
```

The query works when I limit the records but when run it with no limit... Athena query fails after running 20-30 mins. seems like too big of o/p that it can handle. There are no partitions etc. that I can use to load fewer data. I know the file it will generate in S3 for query o/p will be in GBs. Is there a way I can make this query better that Athena likes it, or do you have any other thoughts on how to achieve this?

I also tried to create a new table from the query o/p, but it seems eventual; first, the query needs to be completed before it will create a new table.

CREATE TABLE common_md5 (above query)

Comment: do an inner join. see if that helps. And do a select distinct in the CTEs

Comment: Perhaps: `select md5 from table1 where md5 in (select md5 from table2)`

Comment: Or as a join: `select md5 from table1 inner join table2 using (md5)`